# HTML/CSS Responsive NavBar and Alignment

Tags: html, css

I am working to create a NavBar very similar to Apple's from scratch in order to learn HTML. Here is what I have so far after reading a book and pulling from a few online sources to try and properly format it. I am having difficulty vertically aligning the menu items inside the NavBar itself so they are not lower than center... Same with the logo at the beginning (is there a different way I should be handling this logo? Also I changed the logo file name because it wouldn't be of use here but I didn't want to remove the line from my code.)

Besides centering the text vertically, I also do not know how to center the text items and logo when the menu is open during the mobile view's activation. I thought inline would work but that does not seem to work within my code.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align:center
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  transition : 0.3s;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px 60px 0px 60px;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: #4286f4;
}

.active {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #4286f4;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 9px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: static}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 9px;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#"><img src="Images/Logo.png"width="30" height="30"></a>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

I can't seem to figure this out as I started learning HTML/CSS one week ago and every time I seem to alter one thing another problem appears in its place...

I can edit in my site's domain name if needed, and please refer to Apple.com to get a feel for what I am aiming to create.

Thanks.

Comment: give a class to `<a class='tyh' href="#">` to every link, then `float:left;` your class, also add `padding` to put space between your links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)) on your `.topnav` and set to align and justify the content in the center. That way, all elements inside it will be vertical and horizontally aligned.

For the example, I removed some styles you had (such as media queries) to let the example more clear, And change the margin between `.topnav a` because for the snippet here it was too much, but you can use the amount you want.

See below if it helps:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  transition : 0.3s;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: #4286f4;
}

.active {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #4286f4;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x30" width="30" height="30"/></a>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Great this is just what I was looking for, looks very nice. I am just going to add some padding to the top and bottom of the logo since my logo is a circle and takes up the whole area and doesn't look great.

My second question though relates to the media queries... Now when I hit the assigned pixel width and click on my menu, can I use the same flex rules to make the menu items appear vertically while centered in the drop down NavBar?

Comment: Let's go by parts. If this answer solves your original question, please consider to mark it as accepted answer and/or upvote. If you have now another question, please, open a new question, since this one is already solved and the question and the answer might help other people looking for the same topic.

Comment: Ok thank you my friend. Very sorry, I am obviously new to these forums, I must learn the ins and outs of posting. Cheers and thanks for answering the question I will mark it as solved now.